# Angular.Dart and the Root Controller/Component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an Angular.Dart program and want to add some Angular functionality to the main program (outside of any components). I've been reading about how to accomplish this, and it seems that you have to use the .rootContextType property to accomplish this.

This is my main() function before I tried anything, and it's working fine:

```dart
main() {
  applicationFactory()
      .addModule(new MainInitModule())
      .run();
}
```

Next, I defined an empty class (to be my Root Controller) as follows:

```dart
 @Injectable()
 class RootController {

 }
```

And I modified my main() function as follows:

```dart
main() {
  applicationFactory()
      .rootContextType(RootController)
      .addModule(new MainInitModule())
      .run();
}
```

Trying to run this produce the following error messages / stack traces:

```
Missing getter: (o) => o.openAction

STACKTRACE:
#0      StaticFieldGetterFactory.getter (package:angular/change_detection/dirty_checking_change_detector_static.dart:12:25)
#1      DirtyCheckingRecord.object= (package:angular/change_detection/dirty_checking_change_detector.dart:545:43)
#2      _FieldHandler.acceptValue (package:angular/change_detection/watch_group.dart:631:17)
#3      WatchGroup.addFieldWatch (package:angular/change_detection/watch_group.dart:167:29)
#4      FieldReadAST.setupWatch (package:angular/change_detection/ast.dart:68:31)
#5      WatchGroup.addCollectionWatch (package:angular/change_detection/watch_group.dart:176:49)
#6      CollectionAST.setupWatch (package:angular/change_detection/ast.dart:139:36)
#7      WatchGroup._addEvalWatch (package:angular/change_detection/watch_group.dart:235:52)
#8      WatchGroup.addFunctionWatch (package:angular/change_detection/watch_group.dart:199:20)
#9      PureFunctionAST.setupWatch (package:angular/change_detection/ast.dart:88:34)
#10     WatchGroup.watch (package:angular/change_detection/watch_group.dart:141:62)
#11     Scope.watchAST (package:angular/core/scope.dart:271:23)
#12     AttrMustache.AttrMustache.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core_dom/mustache.dart:38:32)
#13     NodeAttrs.listenObserverChanges (package:angular/core_dom/directive.dart:79:13)
#14     AttrMustache.AttrMustache (package:angular/core_dom/mustache.dart:34:33)
#15     ElementBinder._createDirectiveFactories (package:angular/core_dom/element_binder.dart:259:11)
#16     ElementBinder.bind (package:angular/core_dom/element_binder.dart:294:32)
#17     ViewFactory._bindTagged (package:angular/core_dom/view_factory.dart:79:36)
#18     ViewFactory._link (package:angular/core_dom/view_factory.dart:119:24)
#19     ViewFactory.call (package:angular/core_dom/view_factory.dart:58:10)
#20     Application.run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/application.dart:186:24)
#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:902)
#22     _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:508)
#23     _onRunUnary.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:63)
#24     VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:104:16)
#25     _onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:17)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:804)
#27     _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:484)
#28     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567)
#29     _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:358)
#30     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:412)
#31     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:895)
#32     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:501)
#33     _onScheduleMicrotask.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:127:45)
#34     VmTurnZone._finishTurn (package:angular/core/zone.dart:166:34)
#35     VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:111:43)
#36     _onRun (package:angular/core/zone.dart:118:17)
#37     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:796)
#38     VmTurnZone.run (package:angular/core/zone.dart:257:40)
#39     Application.run (package:angular/application.dart:174:22)
#40     main (http://localhost:8080/datacea.dart:157:11)
#41     main (http://localhost:8080/datacea.html_bootstrap.dart:93:11)

The null object does not have a method 'call'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Instance of 'RootController']

STACKTRACE:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#1      DirtyCheckingRecord.check (package:angular/change_detection/dirty_checking_change_detector.dart:569:26)
#2      DirtyCheckingChangeDetector.collectChanges (package:angular/change_detection/dirty_checking_change_detector.dart:353:26)
#3      RootWatchGroup.detectChanges (package:angular/change_detection/watch_group.dart:398:69)
#4      RootScope.flush (package:angular/core/scope.dart:860:38)
#5      Scope.apply (package:angular/core/scope.dart:317:23)
#6      RootScope.RootScope.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/scope.dart:768:12)
#7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:895)
#8      _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:501)
#9      VmTurnZone._finishTurn (package:angular/core/zone.dart:168:21)
#10     VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:111:43)
#11     _onRun (package:angular/core/zone.dart:118:17)
#12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:796)
#13     VmTurnZone.run (package:angular/core/zone.dart:257:40)
#14     Application.run (package:angular/application.dart:174:22)
#15     main (http://localhost:8080/datacea.dart:157:11)
#16     main (http://localhost:8080/datacea.html_bootstrap.dart:93:11)

The null object does not have a method 'call'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Instance of 'RootController']

STACKTRACE:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#1      DirtyCheckingRecord.check (package:angular/change_detection/dirty_checking_change_detector.dart:569:26)
#2      DirtyCheckingChangeDetector.collectChanges (package:angular/change_detection/dirty_checking_change_detector.dart:353:26)
#3      RootWatchGroup.detectChanges (package:angular/change_detection/watch_group.dart:398:69)
#4      RootScope.flush.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/scope.dart:884:57)
#5      RootScope.flush (package:angular/core/scope.dart:896:9)
#6      Scope.apply (package:angular/core/scope.dart:317:23)
#7      RootScope.RootScope.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/scope.dart:768:12)
#8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:895)
#9      _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:501)
#10     VmTurnZone._finishTurn (package:angular/core/zone.dart:168:21)
#11     VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:111:43)
#12     _onRun (package:angular/core/zone.dart:118:17)
#13     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:796)
#14     VmTurnZone.run (package:angular/core/zone.dart:257:40)
#15     Application.run (package:angular/application.dart:174:22)
#16     main (http://localhost:8080/datacea.dart:157:11)
#17     main (http://localhost:8080/datacea.html_bootstrap.dart:93:11)

Exception: The null object does not have a method 'call'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Instance of 'RootController'] (package:angular/change_detection/dirty_checking_change_detector.dart:569)
```

I've been racking my brain over how to resolve this for three days now with no success. Can anyone assist?

Comment: There is no error in the code that you posted. Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @Ozan - just added error / stack trace.

Comment: There seems to be a reference to a `openAction` in a template somewhere. It can not be found in the scope and then these types of errors appear.

Comment: But everything is working perfectly prior to me adding the line ".rootContextType(RootController)" to main(). What gives?

Comment: I don't understand it fully either. It seems that after adding a rootContextType Angular looks for openAction in there, unsuccessfully.

Comment: If you can think of anything I can do to debug the issue please don't hesitate to chime in - I will try anything at this point, within reason :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67960/discussion-between-ozan-and-greg-sherman).

Comment: I troubleshooted this issue to the fact that I was using Angular and Polymer in this project and have overridden dependencies to make this happen. This dependency override is what's triggering the error message.